# What do you call this type of plug?

Tags: identification, plug

What do you call this plug as a whole? It has two pins and a grounding/earthing wire protuding out. As I do not know the name of this plug, I do not know how to properly use it or even know that it is safe to use. Is it a fire hazard to use this kind of plug?

[image: image of the connector]

It came inside the box when I bought a Philips monitor. It is supposed to be the mains cable that connects to the outlet.

Comment: It's a lug terminal. It supposed to be screwed on the metal case.

Comment: Can you state the region you're located in? Nothing I've ever purchased had a wire coming out of the wall plug.

Comment: Are you in Japan? Or are you outside of Japan and you ordered a monitor from Japan?

Comment: I call it a blur.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a fork terminal for a grounding lead. One's supposed to mount that to a grounding post, as illustrated on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#NEMA_1).

Do not forget to slide back the protective plastic cover, so the metal connection makes contact with the metal exposed by the grounding post. The screw of the grounding post goes between the two metal prongs.

Installing the grounding connection is generally recommended. Do consult the manual.

Alternatively, if the cord is removable from the monitor or its power supply, and you have grounded (3-hole) sockets available instead of the grounding posts, you can likely use the usual 3-wire grounded power cables in this cable's place.

[image: socket variant]
[image: mounting]

Comment: Hmm so this kind of plug arrangement does not have an official name of its own? I do not plan to use it as my wall outlet does not look like the one you posted, but a 3 pin one with a slot for a grounding pin.

Yes, the cord is removable from the monitor/power supply and my wall outlet is properly grounded with an attached grounding wire to the receptacle. I will use an IEC C13 female to 3 prong plug male instead (the 3rd pin being a grounding pin). This one https://i.imgur.com/KoRSboh.jpg

Comment: I honestly don't know whether it has a special name (it probably does, something like NEMA 1-15 with a grounding lead :-) ). The answer is based mostly on me seeing those once in the (now correctly) linked wiki article and previous experience. Using the linked NEMA 5-15 plug should just work.

Comment: The power cord that came with my monitor is actually a "IEC C13 Female to Type B Male with a protuding grounding wire plug" lol. My wall outlets are actually of Type B. I would not be needing any NEMA connectors. Just curious if there's really a name for a plug like this...as I thought that every electric plug named is or rather should be standardized!

Comment: If the monitor mains cord is removable, get a proper new mains cord that fits between mains socket and charger inlet.

Comment: @avg9957 Type B *is* NEMA 5-15, so yes, you do need NEMA connectors for it.